# Adding while loop to didMoveToView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a turn-based game which progresses until 13 rounds are over. However, after I created an infinite while loop which would only break after 13 rounds, the scene never loaded. Why is it that the code in `didMoveToView` is executed before the scene shows? Is there a way to fix this or am I possibly doing something wrong?

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    roundFirstCard = Card(key: "2c")
    var actions = [SKAction]()
    let cards = makeDeck()
    for c in cards {
        let card = Card(key: c)
        card.name = card.key
        card.position = CGPointMake(500, 400)
        addChild(card)
        giveCardToCorrectPlayer(cards.indexOf(c)!, c: card)
        actions.append(SKAction.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(getTargetLocationForCard(cards.indexOf(c)!), duration: 1.0), onChildWithName: card.name!))
        actions.append(SKAction.waitForDuration(0.05))
    }
    actions.append(SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0))
    playerCardSets = [player1Cards, player2Cards, player3Cards, player4Cards]
    self.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actions), completion: {self.spreadCards()})
    currentPlayer = 1
    while true {}
}
```

Comment: What code have you written?

Comment: You can't iterate over a group of SKNodes and run actions in them and expect to see the results in didMoveToView. This function is called and when it's complete sprite-kit draws the scene as it is when didMoveToView ended and then starts the SK game loop.

Comment: if you are doing transitions, then didMoveToView fires immediately,  you need to check the didMoveFromView on the old scene to determine if the new scene is the only scene present

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by old and new? There is only one scene.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a while loop, especially if your scene is a round.
So I suppose this scene you've write in your question is a typical round of your game.
You can save the rounds number in `NSUserDefaults` for example in AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "roundCounter")
     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
     return true
}
```

So in your scene you know what is your round:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    var roundCounter = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("roundCounter")
    roundCounter += 1 //Start new round
    guard let r = roundCounter where r > 13 {
        gameOver() //launch gameOver function
        return
    }
    // do your stuff
    // save the actual round number 
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(roundCounter, forKey: "roundCounter")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

func gameOver() {
   // reset to zero your round counter
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "roundCounter")
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
   //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: There is only one scene for all thirteen rounds, so I'm a little confused by the answer

Comment: In your code it doesn't understand when the game is over, too few code, can you post more code so I will try to help you, PS remove while true {} , it's not correct, and explain better what do you want to achieve with a while loop